# c++, Check user input againest 2D array data

Tags: c++, c++17

I am making a program for our final project, the program contains login / sign up.

I have made a struct data contains a 2D array which contains 100 rows (maximum number of students that can the array contains) and 2 columns (one for matric number and one for password).

```
struct StudentsData {

    string AccessData[100][2] = {
        {"1912765", "1234567"},
    };

};
StudentsData sData;
```

in login function I have done the following, but it always goes to else condition even tho my login data is correct.

```
void login() {
    string  CheckMatric, CheckPassword;
    system("CLS");
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Matric number: " << endl;
    cin >> CheckMatric;
    cout << "Enter Password: " << endl;
    cin >> CheckPassword;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(sData.AccessData); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(sData.AccessData[i]); j++) {
            if (CheckMatric == sData.AccessData[i][j]) 
                if(CheckPassword == sData.AccessData[i][j]) {
                cout << "Successfully logged in" << endl;
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                int choice;
                cout << "oops, wrong username or password, try again or call +60...... for support" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Enter 1 to try again OR Enter 2 to sign up " << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cin >> choice;
                if (choice == 1)
                    login();
                else if (choice == 2)
                    signup();
                else if (choice == 0)
                    exit(0);
                else {
                    cout << "Opps, you will start from the begining :( " << endl;
                    first_interface();

                }       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

lastly, the sign up function, also I am not sure if this is a correct way to assign the input to the array.

```
void signup() {
    system("CLS");
    string NewMatricNo, NewPassword;
    cout << "Enter Your Matric Number: " << endl;
    cin >> NewMatricNo;
    cout << "Enter Password : " << endl;
    cin >> NewPassword;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(sData.AccessData); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(sData.AccessData); j++) {
            NewMatricNo = sData.AccessData[i][j];
            NewPassword = sData.AccessData[i][j];
        }
    }
     cout << "Successfully signed up! " << endl;

}
```

Comment: Hint: Since you're using `sData.AccessData[i][j]` in both of your comparisons, the Matric number and password have to be the same.

Comment: Also, your use of `sizeof` is incorrect. `sizeof` returns the size in bytes of an object, not the number of elements in an array.

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector` instead of fixed-length C-style arrays. The `100` here is an *assumption* that you'll never need more than that. It also means you allocate for the worst-case scenario every time. Don't have hard maximums if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming both CheckMatric and CheckPassword have to be equal to sData.AccessData[i][j], which means the password would have to be the same as the username, which is probably not what you want. You should get rid of the j for-loop altogether. And have the username compare to the first element of the row and the password compare to the second element of the row.

```
size_t n = sizeof(sData.AccessData)/sizeof(sData.AccessData[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (CheckMatric == sData.AccessData[i][0] &&
            CheckPassword == sData.AccessData[i][1]) {
            cout << "Successfully logged in" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
// login failed... prompt user here
```

The else statement inside the for loop means if the login fails on the first account in the Accessdata the login will fail completely, so it needs to be moved out. Since your function exits on successful login anyway, the for-loop completing is a good indicator that the login failed and you can prompt the user for options then. Also, shown is the proper way to get the number of rows in the array into an integer n.

Comment: This answer was to your specific problem, a better way to implement a login database would be using [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), where checking for successful login would be as simple as if(AccessData[user] == password) {...} with no loop. It's generally a good idea to check for existing structs for your problem before attempting to implement it on your own.